# Get output while using putty remotely

Tags: windows, command-line, putty

I have two different servers (A and B, both are Windows) and I am executing putty via command line between them. Server A executes remotely an script in server B and everything works fine, but I am not able to get the output (ERRORLEVEL) in server A once the script has been executed in server B. I mean, I can get the output but always says that the process has finished successfully even if the process in server B has failed.

I attach an small example of the process (ExProcess.bat) I have in server B:

```
set LOG_PATH=C:\Project\Logs
set BIN_PATH=C:\Project\bin

cd %BIN_PATH%
C:
echo %date% %time% >> %LOG_PATH%\logfile.txt
EXECUTE_MY_COMMAND >> %LOG_PATH%\logfile.txt
if not %ERRORLEVEL%==0 exit %ERRORLEVEL%
```

And this is how I am making the remote call from server A:

```
putty -ssh server02 -P 22 -l user1 -pw password1 -m C:\Project\SSH_PRG0001_CMPG0001.txt
```

SSH_PRG0001_CMPG0001.txt contains the remote batch (C:\ExProcess.bat)

If I execute in Windows Command line %ERRORLEVEL% once I have executed the putty command I am not getting the correct output of the process I have run remotely.

I have checked that the remote process is returning the correct output error in server B, but my problem is that I cannot get this output from server A.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

As you're discovering, this won't work.

`%ERRORLEVEL%` (which is not, in fact, "output", but rather a function of the local shell) returns the status of the last command executed; on server B, that's `EXECUTE_MY_COMMAND`, as you want it to be -- but on A, it's instead `putty`! Since Putty successfully connected and did its thing, `%ERRORLEVEL%` is 0, as it should be.

You could modify your script on B to end with something like `echo %ERRORLEVEL%` (instead of your `if` statement), then capture that output on A (e.g. via redirection) and react accordingly. Or, whatever it is on A that's responding to the result, you could consider reacting on B instead, making the entire process entirely self-contained on server B and merely triggered by the connection from A.

Comment: Thanks for your response.                                           I have added "echo" at the end of the script instead of using the IF statement, but when I try to redirect the output to a flat file it doesn't write anything. For example: putty -ssh server02 -P 22 -l user1 -pw password1 -m C:\Project\SSH_PRG0001_CMPG0001.txt > C:\file.txt                                                          Thanks

Comment: When you run it without the redirection, do you see the expected output?

Comment: I see that the process fails and it writes 1 (echo 1 when fails), but I cannot get this error from the server that is making the remote call